# Runtime modification of Spring @Retryable maxAttempts value

Tags: spring, runtime, spring-retry

**Scenario :** I need to modify maxAttempts value of **`@Retryable`** at runtime, so that the number of retries can be driven from database

```java
@Service
public class PropertyHolder {
 private int retryCount= 2; 
 public int retryCount() { return retryCount; }
 
 @Scheduled(fixedRate=3600000) //Query DB and update retryCount every 60mins
 private void updateRetryCount(int in) {
   this.retryCount = 0; //Fetch retryCount from DB and update retryCount
 }
}


@Service
public class SimpleService{
 @Retryable( value={ Throwable.class }, maxAttemptsExpression="#{@propertyHolder.retryCount()}")
 private void performTask() {
   // do some opertion that throws Exception
 }
}
```

`PropertyHolder` will update `retryCount` once in every 60 minutes.
This `PropertHolder#retryCount` needs to be wired to  `@Retryable` in `SimpleService#performTask` .
At present, it takes only the initial value of retryCount (2).
Is this a right approach or Am I making some terrible mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; currently the expression is only evaluated during context initialization; there is an open feature request to add runtime evaluation.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry/issues/184

Currently you have to wire up your own interceptor with a mutable retry policy and configure it via the `interceptor` property in `@Retryable`.